# Issue with reading values from Multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a question where in i need to take coordinates entered by the user (separated by spaces) into a Multi-dimensional array. I'm trying to separate the 'x' and 'y' values and store them separately in a single dimension array say x[i] and y[i].

The issue i'm facing here is i'm not able to read the 'y' values from the array. when i'm trying to output the array containing y values, it is just displaying only 0's. kindly help me on this on how do i rectify this issue. please find my code below.

(Note: N = number of rows in the multi-dimensional array, columns is fixed to 2) (Sorry, forget R, used for some other purpose)

```
public class Read{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int  N = 1, R=1;
    double AoN=1;
    float d=0 , e=0, s=0, length=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    System.out.println("Enter values of N and R separated by space: ");

    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        arr[i]=in.nextInt();
            if (arr[0]>=1 && arr[0]<=100) {
                N=arr[0]; //storing N 
            }
                R=arr[1]; //storing R
    }

    float[ ][ ] arr1 = new float[N][2];
    System.out.println("Enter Coordinates seperated by spaces: ");
    for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
          for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
              arr1[i][j]=in.nextFloat();
              //System.out.println(arr1[i][j]);
              }   
      }
    float[] x = new float[N];
    float[] y = new float[2]; // I've given 2 here coz the coordinates are always x and y. please correct me if im wrong.

    for(int i=0; i<N;i++) {
              x[i] = arr1[i][0];
              System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
    for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
              y[j] = arr1[0][j];
          System.out.println(y[j]);

    }
```

Input:

```
2 1 (N, R)
0 0 (x1, y1)
1 3 (x2, y2)
```

Output:

```
0.0 (x1)
1.0 (x2)
0.0 (y1)
0.0 (y2)
```

The output of the array containing 'y' values is always 0 (should be 0 and 3). kindly help. thanks.

Comment: I wish you chose better naming for your variables name :)

Comment: What is N? What is R? You are free to choose arbitrary undescriptive names for identifiers that make reading your code very hard, but then please add comments that explain what they are supposed to be. thanks

Comment: N is the number of rows of the multi-dimensional array, and the column is fixed to 2. please find the updated question.

Comment: As far as I can see you store your `y` value in `arr1[i][1]`; Think where you are trying to retrieve it from

Comment: @GermannArlington yes.you are right. it should be arr[ j ][ 1 ]. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a bug here...

```
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        y[j] = arr1[0][j]; // <<< HERE!!
        System.out.println(y[j]);
    }
```

I think you mean...

```
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        y[j] = arr1[j][1];
        System.out.println(y[j]);
    }
```

With the parameters you entered, by the time the code gets to the "float[] x =..." bit, the state of the "arr"s is...

```
arr = [2, 1]
arr1 = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 3.0]]
```

The second block is always selecting the first element of the 2d array which has "0" for each value of "j"

Comment: Yes. you were right. thank u for pointing it out. its working fine now. Since its a multi dimensional array, we have to take the first element as 'j' and second element as '1'. since the values are 01, 11 and so on. thanks again.